# Bootstrap popover pushes button down

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap popover on my image.

When I click on image it shows the popover fine but buttons are pushed down for some reason.

Question: How to make the buttons in line show inline on bootstrap popover over image no matter what size image is.

Codepen Example [here](http://codepen.io/wolfgang1983/pen/yaQKZP)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var popupElement = '<div class="btn-group btn-toggle"><button class="btn btn-sm btn-info">On</button><button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary active">Off</button></div>';

    $('#image').popover({
        animation: true,
        content: popupElement,
        html: true
    });
});   
</script>
```

View

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
<img id="image" src="holder.js/100px164" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">  
</div>  
</div>  
</div>
```

Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add following code on your css

```
.btn-group{display: flex;}
```

or someone have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://codepen.io/divyanshu013/pen/rrQdGv) is a working fork of your pen. I've simply added this to the CSS. Seems like the popover is lacking the width to display the buttons inline:

```
.popover  {
  width: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make this work is adding a width to the container element. Something like this:

```
.btn-group {
  width: 100px; //sample value
}
```

I hope to have helped in some way